# How to dynamically retrieve the executing procedure's database name in Snowflake?

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Within a Snowflake JavaScript stored procedure, I would like to retrieve the executing procedure's database name (and preferably schema name too). Can this be done? And if so, how?

**Why?**

1. The procedure builds dynamic SQL for tables expected to be in the same database as the SP, using fully-qualified object names.
2. The goal is for both these (semi-generic) tables and the procedure to be deployed to multiple databases as appropriate, using identical table/procedure DDL (stored in VCS).
3. If really curious, this is for automated provisioning of multi-tenant row-level security access via Tableau, to a variety of different environments & databases in Snowflake.

*Note:* It cannot depend on the current session, as that could be with a different database, while a different database's stored procedure is being called using the fully-qualified name. (i.e. `<database>.<schema>.<procedure>`)

*Also note:* It's not as simple as statically defining it within the procedure, as this is something that could be deployed to multiple databases (i.e. different environments), and it's not practical to change the SP body for each one.

Some conceptual approaches could be...

Using a built-in JavaScript object like this one (which gets just the procedure name):

```
var proc_name = Object.keys(this)[0];
```

Using a built-in SQL function like this one (which retrieves the session's DB, not the procedure's DB):

```
var result = snowflake.execute({sqlText: 'select current_database()'});
result.next();
var db_name = result.getColumnValue(1);
```

Or, another creative solution?

If not possible, maybe someone can point me to an existing Snowflake feature request?

Comment: I would put the `{{DATABASE}}` that is used in the CREATE command inside the body of the proceedure, so when the procedure is created those details are already captured... This might work in your deployment env.

Comment: I'm not sure whether there is a way to do what you want, but perhaps if you can explain *why* you want to reference the containing database of a stored procedure from inside the procedure itself that might help people suggest options for you.

Comment: @NathanGriffiths the reason is two-fold: 1) The procedure builds dynamic SQL for  tables expected to be in the same database as the stored procedure, using fully-qualified object names. 2) The intent is for both these (semi-generic) tables and the procedure to be deployed to multiple databases as appropriate, using identical table/procedure DDL (stored in VCS).

Comment: @ElCarverino how does having the database name in the SP help with deploying it to multiple databases? Deployment happens outside of the SP. Are you doing cross-database references within the stored procedure?

Comment: I would simply use the schema and object names in the SP (which are presumably the same in every database) and then set the database context in the calling process, i.e. `USE DATABASE XXXX`

Comment: @NathanGriffiths, while the SP is not doing cross-database references, the calling process is, and thus, the inclusion of the DB name, to be safe. And yeah, that's the current workaround, to force the calling processes to declare a database (and the desired one) when connecting. This requires disconnecting and re-connecting afterwards, to resume the db-agnostic approach for cross-database calls.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions; these are technically effective ways to get the desired end result, just not as convenient for our automation. I inquired because it's something I've been able to do in several other DB systems and was hoping Snowflake might have something similar.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that asking the [information_schema](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/procedures) for the match procedure should do the trick:

```
use test.test;
```

```
create or replace procedure where_am_i()
returns text
language javascript
as $$
    var sql_command = "select PROCEDURE_CATALOG, PROCEDURE_SCHEMA from information_schema.procedures where procedure_name = 'WHERE_AM_I'";
    var statement1 = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: sql_command} );
    var result_set1 = statement1.execute();
    if(result_set1.next()){
       var column1 = result_set1.getColumnValue(1);
       var column2 = result_set1.getColumnValue(2);
       var answer = column1 + '.' + column2;
        return answer;
    }
    return undefined;
$$;
```

```
create schema not_test;
use schema test.not_test;
call test.test.where_am_i();
```

[image]

different db & schema:

```
create database not_test;
create schema not_test.also_not_test;
use schema not_test.also_not_test;
call test.test.where_am_i();
```

[image]